# Display render div message in gsp file

Tags: grails, render

I already have div tag with `id="myDiv"` like

`<div id="myDiv"></div>`

Is it possible to display the message using

```
render div (id:'myDiv', 'text')
```

instead of creating a new div tag.

Comment: You can use [template](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/render.html), instead of trying to populate div elements in DOM. You can also render a template in view using `g:render` tag when required.

Comment: Could you please elaborate with example?

Comment: please add some context to your question

Comment: I make a action Ajax call in gsp file for validation, on success it should display the validation message based on the action in the controller and display it on the view.

Answer (score 0):

In your file.gsp you can use template as suggest dmahapatro.

E.g.

action in controller

```
//some code

render (view: 'actionName', model: [text: text])
```

actionName.gsp

```
//some code

<div id="myDiv">${text}</div>
```